# ¿Cómo usar por segunda vez las bibliotecas instaladas previamente en Pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm, sympy

soy nueva usando Python y Pycharm.

Acabo de hacer un código (literal mi primer código) donde uso las librerías matplotlib, sympy y numpy. Pero estoy haciendo otro código (mi segundo código, en el mismo proyecto) donde importo las librerías y me dice que no están instaladas. Sale `Unused import statement 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'` luego voy a Python Interpreter, instalo las librerías de nuevo y no me deja cliquear en "Apply" entonces no se aplican a mi nuevo archivo.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Ese es un error que se da en ocasiones cuando se importa la misma cosa dos veces dentro de un mismo proyecto en `Pycharm`. Puedes probar dos cosas:

1. Borrar la segunda importación y en su lugar importar el módulo en que se halla la primera. Si usas `name == 'main'` no habrá problemas con el código que contenga el archivo.
2. Borrar ambas importaciones y en su lugar importar un módulo creado al efecto con  las importaciones en su interior.

De este modo tendrás una sola importación y `Pycharm` no protestará, el segundo caso es el más lógico y seguro.

Por cierto, este error se da también en `PHPStorm`, etc.